# NVD3 X axis incorrect ordering (dates)

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to visualize 2 series but when I visualize them together, the dates don't go in sequential order anymore.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hohenheim/6R7mu/21/ Notice the weird x-axis.

Is there a way to fix the x axis on nvd3?

The data looks like this:

```
data1 = [{
      "date": 1396828800,
      "impressions": 49145385
  }, {
      "date": 1396915200,
      "impressions": 46704447
  } ....
```

Comment: Not sure what you're doing there, but you need to convert the dates to `Date` objects for the time scale to work properly.

Comment: I explicitly converted to `Date` and I get the same problem:http://jsfiddle.net/hohenheim/6R7mu/21/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NVD3 "multiBarChart" uses an ordinal (category) scale, so it will only display the x-values you give it, in the order in which they are added to the scale.  Because your two series only partially overlap on the x axis that's causing problems.

Unlike other NVD3 chart types, the multiBarChart doesn't give you the option of setting your own scale -- it needs to use an ordinal scale in order to generate even widths for the bars.  However, you can set the x domain (the list of categories to use for each bar), by calling `chart.xDomain(arrayOfXValues)`.

The array will need to be an ordered array of Date values that spans your data.  In order to generate it, you'll need the [d3 time intervals `range` functions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Intervals#interval_range). You might also need the [`d3.extent` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_extent) to find your max and min values.